# What does "protected user interface elements" mean

Tags: .net

When configuring the `requestedExecutionLevel` in an manifest, there is a setting option `uiAccess` which "Indicates whether the application requires access to protected user interface elements"
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad1fshk.aspx)

What exactly does "`protected user interface elements`" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `uiAccess` option to true means that your application intends to interact with windows belonging to applications running at a higher privilege level than yours. This is for accessibility programs such as on-screen keyboards, which need to send messages to all windows regardless of their privilege level. As the article states, if you set this value to true, you must also digitally sign your application.